# Reactjs + material UI: Drop down menu doesn't select the item

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to build a drop down menu in a modal popup window with using Material UI

I have drop down menu in my modal window, and as a value I see the last item is "Third" and when I want to select for instance "First" it doesn't work, the menu doesn't select it and still having the last one item as a value in menu

I have 2 files App.js and list.js

App.js code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {AppButtons} from './components/button'
import {AppList} from './components/list'
import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog'
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton'

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super (props)
        this.state = {
            isModalOpen: false,
            itemsList: [
                {name: 'First'},
                {name: 'Second'},
                {name: 'Third'}
            ],
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange = () => this.setState({this.state.itemsList});

    render() {
        const actions = [
            <FlatButton
                label="Save"
                primary={true}
                onClick={() => this.setState({isModalOpen: false})}
            />,
            <FlatButton
                label="Cancel"
                primary={true}
                onClick={() => this.setState({isModalOpen: false})}
            />,
        ];
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <AppButtons
            openModal = {() => this.setState ({isModalOpen: true})}
        />
        <Dialog
            title="Numbers structure"
            actions={actions}
            open={this.state.isModalOpen}
            onRequestClose={() => this.setState({isModalOpen: true})}
        >
            <AppList
            items = {this.state.itemsList}
            />
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And list.js code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import DropDownMenu from 'material-ui/DropDownMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

const styles = {
    customWidth: {
        width: 200,
    },
};

export const AppList = (props) => {
    return (
<div>
    <DropDownMenu
       style={styles.customWidth}
       onChange={this.handleChange}
    >
        {props.items.map((item, key) => {
            return (
                <MenuItem
                          primaryText = {item.name}
                          openImmediately={true}
                          autoWidth={false}/>
            )
        })
        }
    </DropDownMenu>
    <br />
</div>
)
}
```

[Here is the shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij4hh.png)

Comment: function handleChange must be included in list.js too

Comment: or you can just pass that function in props and call it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you aren't passing down your `handleChange` function as a prop to `<AppList/>`:

```
<AppList 
    items = {this.state.itemsList}
/>
```

Change it to:

```
<AppList 
    items = {this.state.itemsList}
    handleChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

And then in your `AppList` component, the `Dropdown` component needs to use `this.props.handleChange` instead of `this.handleChange`:

```
<DropDownMenu
   style={styles.customWidth}
   onChange={this.props.handleChange}
>
    ...
</DropDownMenu>
```

Comment: Thank you Chase for helping me out!

I have changed like you showed me, but I have received this error in list.js file: 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleChange' of undefined

 And  this line marked as a red: onChange={this.props.handleChange}

I suppose that handleChange function is not visible in list.js but don't know how to fix it

Comment: Ah sorry, it's a stateless component. Change it from `this.props.handleChange` to `props.handleChange` and it should work.

Comment: You are passing in `props` to `<AppList />`, so that's where you need to get the change handler from.

Comment: Thank you, the error is disappeared but still doesn't work functional, I think maybe something wrong in this line: handleChange = () => this.setState({itemsList: this.state.itemsList});

Comment: Yeah that won't work. You need to give `setState` an object. Should be `this.setState({ name: value })`, not what you have. You need to look up what `Dropdown` returns as a param to the `handleChange` function and then use that to update some state. You don't have it setup correctly in your example, so I have no idea what you're trying to do.